# JUnit 5 AfterAll not executed on Kotlin

Tags: junit, kotlin, junit5

If I run the `SubClass` unit below I expect `@AfterAll` to be executed after the test. Yet, the output is just this:

```
init in super class
init in sub class
test OK
```

I don't understand why `SuperClass#stop()` is not invoked. I understand that `@AfterAll` requires a static method or `Lifecycle.PER_CLASS` but this is given.

**Super class**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
open class SuperClass {

    init {
        println("init in super class")
    }

    @AfterAll
    fun stop(){
        println("service stopped")
    }
}
```

**Sub class**

```
import org.junit.Test

open class SubClass : SuperClass() {

    init {
        println("init in sub class")
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldRun() {
        println("test OK")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Test.html) instead of `org.junit.Test` in your JUnit5-tests (check also [JUnit 5 User Guide - Annotations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations)).

The following will work as expected:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

open class SubClass : SuperClass() {
  init {
    println("init in sub class")
  }

  @Test
  fun shouldRun() {
    println("test OK")
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonder why we didn't renamed `@Test` to `@Te5t` ... or `@T357`. ;-)

Comment: Argg, bloody hell...Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I'm glad I included the imports.

Comment: yes, that helped a bit ;-) but to be honest: it happended to me too... maybe `@Te5t` would really have made things easier ;-)